# how to a query to match the records in two different tables and if a match update with new values, no match prompt me to fill in the details?

Tags: sql, jsp

I have two tables

```
+---------------------------------+
|             Table A             |
+----------+-----------+----+-----+
| Part No  | Serial No | PO |  DO |
+----------+-----------+----+-----+
| 1AB1009  | GR7764    | ST | OND |
| 1AB1009  | GR7765    | ST | OND |
+----------+-----------+----+-----+

+-----------+
|  Table B  |
+-----------+
| Serial No |
+-----------+
|   GR7764  |
|   GR7765  |
+-----------+
```

Table B have only one column with unique serial no's, am matching the serial no in both tables and updating the values if there is a match...my query is running nice for this but I have a scenario like first I upload a csv file to Table B then I will match...but Table A may not have some serial no's, so if there is no match it should prompt me to go the add page to add the records to Table A and then perform update query.

This is my query

```
update TableA 
   set Mat_No ='"+ Mat_No+"',WO_No='"+WO_No+"',Code = '"+Code+"',
       Desc = '"+Desc+"',Center='"+Center+"',Date='"+Date+"',Remarks='"+Remarks+"' 
 where SerialNo in(select A.SerialNo 
                     from Table A, Table B 
                    where B.SerialNo = A.SerialNo and A.Status = 'IN');
```

First I will upload a csv file to table B then I fill all the details like MatNo etc then update if the csv file is having the serial no which are not in Table A then it should prompt me with all the serial no's no match in table A.... don't know how to do this?? Please help me out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps you can do:

Load the CSV files (using any of BCP, BULK INSERT, Import export wizard, SSIS packages) for loading tableB. This process is independent of updating tableA.

Now for TableA  create an update trigger that checks for all the SNOs present in B and NOT in A while updating it. See below DDLs and queries as example and accordingly modify:

```
    create  table TABLEA (
     PartNo varchar(30),
     SNo varchar(30),
     PO varchar(10),
     DO varchar(30))

     insert into TABLEA 
     select '1AB1009', 'GR7764', 'ST', 'OND'
     union
    select '1AB1009','GR7765','ST','OND'

    create  table TABLEB ( 
     SNo varchar(30)
    )
     insert into TABLEB
     select 'GR7764'
     union
     select 'GR7765'

     select * from TABLEA
     select * from TABLEB
     GO
```

Now create an instead of Update trigger on tableA to warn about SNOs missing in tableA when trying to insert from front end app

```
    CREATE TRIGGER missingSNOs ON TABLEA
    INSTEAD OF UPDATE
    AS  

        BEGIN
            if EXISTS (SELECT 1
                            FROM TABLEB B
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            INSERTED I
                            ON B.SNO = I.SNO
                            WHERE I.SNO IS NULL
                            )
            begin
                     SELECT B.SNO
                            FROM TABLEB B
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN
                            INSERTED I
                            ON B.SNO = I.SNO
                            WHERE I.SNO IS NULL
                RAISERROR('S.nos are missing in tableA which are present in tableB',16,1);
                ROLLBACK;
            end     
        END
    GO
```

Test if the trigger fires when the Sno are missing

```
-- Errors with message as the SNO is missing
update TABLEA
set PartNo = 'newPartNo'
where SNO = 'SnoNOTinB'

-- works no errors as both SNOS are present in tableB
update TABLEA
set PartNo = 'new one'
where SNO in ('GR7764', 'GR7765')

-- Also you dont have to join with tableB now and modify query as below
UPDATE A
set A.Mat_No ='"+ Mat_No+"',WO_No='"+WO_No+"',
Code = '"+Code+"',Desc = '"+Desc+"',
Center='"+Center+"',
Date='"+Date+"',
Remarks='"+Remarks+"' 
FROM TableA A                   
WHERE A.Status = 'IN'
```

Finally clean up the code

```
    drop table TABLEA
      drop table TABLEB
```